# Repeater uses Infinite Scrolling in DotNetNuke

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke, infinite-scroll

I'm using DotNetNuke in my custome module and I'm following the normal asp.net programming methods (drags/drops).
The project is a posting service using repeater with infinite scrolling and masonry effect.
I followed the tutorial posted here : [infinite scrolling](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Infinite-Scroll-Endless-Scroll-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

everything after loading the page is fine. (database connection, the very first records, layout are fine)
but every time I go to the page's bottom it gives a pop up message : Undefined
and no new records appears.

it also can't find the page Posts.aspx/getdata

any help will be highly requested and valuable.

here is the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <section>
                    <article class="masonry">

                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>'/>

                <section class="article-list-box">

                    <p><asp:Label ID="descLBL" runat="server"><%# Eval("Desc")%></asp:Label></p>    

                    <div class="article_meta">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("UserAvatar") %>'/>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article><!-- [article #1 end] -->
                        </section>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

and this is the code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        rptr.DataSource = GetPostData(1);
        rptr.DataBind();
    }          
}

public static DataSet GetPostData(int pageIndex)
{
    string query = "[GetPostsPageWise]";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", pageIndex);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", 10);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PageCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    return GetData(cmd);
}

private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    string strConnString = "My String";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds, "Posts");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("PageCount");
                dt.Columns.Add("PageCount");
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[0][0] = cmd.Parameters["@PageCount"].Value;
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetPS(int pageIndex)
{
    return GetPostData(pageIndex).GetXml();
}
```

and the jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageIndex = 1;
    var pageCount;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            GetRecords();
        }
    });
    function GetRecords() {
        pageIndex++;
        if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
            $("#loader").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Posts.aspx/GetPS",
                data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
        var Posts = xml.find("Posts");
        Posts.each(function () {
            var Posts = $(this);
            var table = $("#portfolio table").eq(0).clone(true);
            $(".masonry", table).html(ad.find("Image").text());
            $(".article-list-box", table).html(ad.find("Desc").text());
            $(".article_meta", table).html(ad.find("UserAvatar").text());
            $("#portfolio").append(table).append("<br />");
        });
        $("#loader").hide();
    }
```

Comment: You need to find out why "Posts.aspx/GetPS" can't be found.  Does it work if you put the full url in?  Can you browse to the full url?

Comment: Hi markpsmith because there is no page in dotnetnuke called getPS. getPS is the webmethod calling to fetch the next records from database

Comment: You should be able to POST to the webmethod with a pageIndex parameter in order to simulate the ajax call. You should be able to use [Fiddler Composer/RequestBuilder](http://www.debugtheweb.com/Fiddler/help/composer.asp) if you can't just browse to it.

Answer (score 0):

here is suggested rewrite:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        rptr.DataSource = GetPostData(1);
        rptr.DataBind();
        if(Request["mode"]!=null){
                int pageIndex = int.Parse( Request["pageIndex"]);
                DataSet ds = GetPostData(pageIndex);
                 System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                 Response.Clear();
                 Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(ds.Tables[0]);
                 //Application.CompleteRequest();
                 Response.End();
        }
    }          
}
```

rewrite your js method with following

```
function GetRecords() {
        pageIndex++;
        if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
            $("#loader").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Posts.aspx?mode=ajax&pageIndex="+pageIndex,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){ alert(response);},
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This should work well for you.

Comment: Thank you Prashant for your response!

Comment: it gives me an error at Application.CompleteRequest(); that I/m missing using directive or assembly reference! when I commented out I still got the Undefined pop up message I just want to know what is the error

Comment: You can replace Application.CompleteRequest with Response.End() for now. response.d is throwing undefined error since response object doesn't contain d. You will get output directly in response object. I updated code accordingly

Comment: now it gives me another pop up error : [object Object]

Comment: also in event viewer there is this message: RawURL: /posts.aspx?mode=ajax&pageIndex=2
AbsoluteURL: /Default.aspx
AbsoluteURLReferrer: /posts.aspx
UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
DefaultDataProvider: DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID: c7ec0e48-c064-4437-9bea-c4d2729ecd31
InnerException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.

Comment: Since you are getting [object Object] you got the data from server in success, replace alert(response) in success function with your success function and instead of using response.d directly use response object.

Comment: the same circular reference detected error is still there, now it's undefined message. sorry for you time